# Connecting to DB2 using SQL Developer

Tags: db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

I trying to connect to DB2 database through SQL Developer. I followed following steps create connection:
1. Open SQL Developer
2. Go to Tools > Preferences > Database > Third Party JDBC Drivers.
3. I added third-party JDBC driver path entries (db2jcc.jar and db2jcc_license_cu.jar)

As soon as I try to create connection I get below error
[image]

Comment: Does SQL Developer even support DB2? Its main site seems to indicate it's for Oracle DBs. SQLCode 204 is an error indicating "<name>" is an undefined name - which probably means SQL Developer is trying to query something in the db that Oracle has but DB2 doesn't.

Comment: Which Db2 version/platform are you connecting to?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL-Developer Version 17.2 works fine for me with Db2 Version 11 for Linux x64 and I am using a recent Type-4 jdbc (db2jcc4.jar) driver from IBM.

You question shows that your Db2 jdbc driver version is very old (Version 9.7 fixpack 5) and out of support, so you should upgrade to the latest available Db2 client for your (unspecified) operating-system. Also you should ensure you are using the latest release of the Oracle-SQL-Developer for your operating system.

As your question gives no facts about your versions of Oracle or Db2 products or operating systems, this is the best advice that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, it turned out SQL Developer doesn't display tables for DB2, but still allows to perform SQL queries. If you know table names, you will be able to select data from those tables if you have enough permissions to do so.

You can test ability to perform SQL queries by selecting DB2 version (SQL below is valid for DB2 12.0)

```
SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION') AS VERSION FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Make sure you don't forget to specify schema while selecting data from your tables!

```
select * from schema.table_name;
```